# Should modules that use HttpClient declare the HttpClientModule in imports?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

[The SVGViewer component](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/master/src/app/shared/svg-viewer/svg-viewer.ts) in the Angular Material documentation app declares its module like this:

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [SvgViewer],
  declarations: [SvgViewer],
})
```

Is it "More" correct for this module to declare:

```
  imports: [HttpClientModule]
```

Since it uses `HttpClient` ?  IIUC in general modules should declare their dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Because it is imported into a module that already imports the HttpClientModule, the dependency injector knows about the HttpClientModule already. See (https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/051363fff1f993dd77f70ea9ebf917fbc3f99426/src/app/app-module.ts)

Comment: It seems like it would be better to declare the dependency for refactoring purposes?

Comment: That could help, but it would be premature optimization until you need it. Better to import the fewest possible dependencies for each module.